# Implementing url rewriting using .htaccess file without affecting $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, server-variables

I want to setup a SaaS(Software as a Service) version of my ERP product. Each of the user who purchases the product can access the product using a url which will be specific for each user (For Example: erp.com/user1/). But there will not be a physical folder created for each user, it will be a virtual one and there will be a single copy of the program file will be there and which will be in the root directory.

I have tried with a htaccess file and here with include the code i have written, it is not generic solution it will work only for the case of 'folder1'

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ /$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is when I implement the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] returns  'erp.com/', instead of this i need to get 'erp.com/folder1/' also please suggest me a generic solution for the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` you need to use:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

that will have value:

```
/folder1/foobar
```

---

**Generic Rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you please help me to find a generic rewrite rule rather than going for specific one like 'RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ /$1 [QSA]', what i am trying to do is in-case any subfolder the files in the root folder. In my case all the sub-folders are conceptual ie, they doesn't exists at all.